# Regex only matches last occurrence

Tags: regex

I have a regex where I want to find all of the empty strings in a SQL statement (and replace them with NULL).

So that this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5) VALUES ('','',"xxx's",'','')
```

Becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (F1,F2,F3,F4,F5) VALUES (NULL,NULL,"xxx's",NULL,NULL)
```

I want to be sure that I am only updating the VALUES() array and this is what I cam up with however this only matches the last occurance of '' and not the other 3 empty strings.

```
/VALUES.*\(.*('').*\)/
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: I don't think you can solve this with a single regex string replace. Can you tell us what language your using and maybe we can suggest an elegant solution?

Comment: Thanks, it is javascript, yes there are several ways to do this in Javascript but I was wondering if it could be achieved only with regex.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. this looks dangerous lol.

I think this would work:

```
myString.replace(/VALUES.*\(.*\)/, function (values) {
  return values.replace(/''/g, 'null');
});
```

While technically still 2 regular expressions, you could make it a one liner with es6 :)

```
myString.replace(/VALUES.*\(.*\)/, str => str.replace(/''/g, 'null'));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping but I was trying to achieve it only using regex, there are quite a few ways to do this if I use other js functions such as split, replace, substr etc.